# ExecuteCaptureLog fails giving memory not available

Tags: ssas, cube

I am processing  **SSAS Cube** programmatically in .net script - `server.ExecuteCaptureLog(true, true)`. It used to work perfectly. Suddenly now a days it started giving error saying

> The operation has been cancelled because there is not enough memory available for the application. If using a 32-bit version of the product, consider upgrading to the 64-bit version or increasing the amount of memory available on the machine.

When we re-run it gives same error with couple of other errors.

> Cursor not found

and

> An error occurred while processing the partition 'partition1_0d0bbd49-7f8c-45c8-91ae-4y66a18b8cc22' in table 'partition1_0d0bbd49-7f8c-45c8-91ae-4y66a18b8cc22'".

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Ranjith

Comment: One more thing, when I removed the partition table 'partition1' from the process, it went through successfully.

Comment: I got my test machine mimicked as production and tried recreating the issue. But it processed successfully. After that Production also started working suddenly. I am waiting for a failure to happen, so that I can have a window for troubleshooting